# Aliens put us on the moon

Tags: science-based, apocalypse, earth, moons, post-apocalypse

So some aliens come, put everyone in space suits, and drop us one the moon. The aliens are super smart, and the space suits have enough air for a year, and can't be damaged easily, and only upon from the inside.  They also drop all artificial stuff (anything that doesn't occur in nature (pasteurized milk counts)) on the earth onto the moon, with the exception of telescopes. The satellites stay where they are. They then go onto the earth, and watch us from our own telescopes.

Short term and long term, what happens to humanity?

Comment: I second [Jimmy360](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/18434/what-if-the-earth-was-turned-physically-inside-out#comment45127_18434); these guys are cruel.

Comment: @HDE226868 Its my standard hand wave (after all, why else would we all be on the moon for? A conference?)

Comment: You seem to be enjoying this fortnightly challenge. And tormenting humanity.

Comment: Well let's either dehydrate or squeeze ourselves to death due to overcrowding.

Answer (score 1):

**Survival:**

We would need to do two things:

1. Rebuild order
2. Terraform the planet

**Terraforming:**

Assuming that we have rebuild order, how would we terraform? First we would build domes. Then we would put oxygen into the domes. Where would we get the oxygen? The answer is [electrolysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrolysis_of_water). Where would we get water if we don't have our plentiful oceans or lakes. We would get them from neutrino detectors. These are basically huge tanks filled with millions of gallons of water. Then we just run electricity from generators through this water, and we channel the oxygen into the domes and the hydrogen gas into separate unpopulated domes for storage (for energy generation later).

[image]

**Food:**

Where would we get food? We already have seed banks to prevent us from losing plant species. We would hydroponically grow these into crops. Maybe GM seeds and animals are teleported since they are a result of human engineering.

Comment: Just our luck, the aliens only teleport the engineered portions of the DNA up to the moon.  Fortunately, the moon has no atmosphere, so nothing will disturb the pile of genomic dust that gets transported our way.

Comment: We're kind of doomed, if there's no way to obtain new food.  Stipulating no ability to grow crops will prevent any reasonable solution.

Comment: Why neutrino detectors? Surely swimming pools and water parks have orders of magnitudes more available water in them. Better hurry though, with no atmosphere everything is boiling away.